# Creating a new calculated column in SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way to find the solution so that I need for 2 days, there are 2 UD's because there are June 24 2 times and for the rest there are single days.

I am showing the expected output here:

```
Primary key   UD    Date
-------------------------------------------
1             123   2015-06-24 00:00:00.000
6             456   2015-06-24 00:00:00.000
2             123   2015-06-25 00:00:00.000
3             658   2015-06-26 00:00:00.000
4             598   2015-06-27 00:00:00.000
5             156   2015-06-28 00:00:00.000
```

```
No of times   Number of days
-----------------------------
4               1
2               2
```

The logic is 4 users are there who used the application on 1 day and there are 2 userd who used the application on 2 days

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Please explain the logic based on the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select cnt, count(*)
from (select date, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by date
     ) d
group by cnt
order by cnt desc;
```